# java generate random "light" color only

Tags: java, random, colors

I need to set a `JPanel` background with **light** colors only in order not to cover the text (in bold black).

At this moment I have this:

```
import java.util.Random;

....

private Random random = new Random();
private JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setBackground( new Color( random.nextInt() ) );
```

But it generates "any" random color.
How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Color` has a constructor that takes three values for red, green and blue. If you give each of them a random value from 100 or so to 255, you will get only light colors.

The usage of the HSB system might give even better results, e.g. 
`new Color(Color.HSBtoRGB((float) Math.random(), (float) Math.random, 0.5F + ((float) Math.random())/2F));`

Answer (score 4):

Create a color [from RGB values](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#Color%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29), and make sure that R, G and B are large enough to make the overall color light. [0, 0, 0] is black. And [255, 255, 255] is white. So you could generate a color with values for R, G and B being random values between 200 and 255 for example.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend not using random colors as a background. It will print ugly background colors and make your program look sloppy.

I recommend you to make a list of beautiful colors and randomly choose one of the colors in the list.

You can find a list of beautiful colors from the webpages below.

http://colorschemedesigner.com/

http://www.colorcombos.com/

http://www.color-swatches.com/top-swatches.html